# Why can't I access an Array outside of a for each loop?

Tags: php, arrays, global

I can't seem to pass to a variable outside of a php for loop.

What am I doing wrong?

I'm trying to build an array from a query
as an example

```
array() [ "A" =>array() [ key=>value, key=>value, key=>value], 
          "B" => array() [ key=>value, key=>value, key=>value]
          etc etc etc
```

The query is returning expected result

```
$sorted=Array();
foreach(range('A', 'Z') as $letter) {
    $rows=Array();
    $query="SELECT `Country`, ROUND(`PeakRate1`, 2) as Rate FROM `VoicePriceLists` where `Country` like '$letter%' and `PeakRate1` != 0 and `DiallingCode` != '64' and `DiallingCode` != 'restricted' group by `Country`";
    if ($result = $link->query($query)) {
        if( $result->num_rows == 0 ) {
            return FALSE;
        } else {
            while($row=$result->fetch_assoc()) {
                // var_dump($letter);
                $rows[]=$row;
            }
        }
        $result->close();
    } else {
        printf("Something major went wrong :( ");
    }
    $sorted[$letter]=$rows;
    var_dump($sorted); // I CAN SEE THE ARRAY GETTING LARGER HERE
}
var_dump($sorted); // NOTHING IN THE ARRAY
```

Expected:

```
Array("A"=>array(key=>value, etc), "B"=>array(key=>value, etc))
```

Comment: Should it be `$rows[$letter][] = ...`? Perhaps just personal preference :P

Comment: This is inside a function, it seems, since you have a return statement there. As soon as you get to a letter where no rows are returned by the query, the function will return false. Not sure if that's causing the problem here, but it seems like it will be a problem in general.

Comment: @Don'tPanic .. perfect; and good spotting .. thanks so much!

Comment: You're welcome!

Comment: after @Don'tPanic pointed out my error the solution was to replace return FALSE; with continue;

Comment: I was also going to suggest running the query without the letter criteria and grouping by letter as you fetch the results. It should be more efficient with one query instead of 26. ;-)

Comment: as Panic stated, just refactor it into one round trip query order it by the country name, then make the grouping after fetching the rows (the array result), not looping all letters.